# how can I create a category for ungrouped data?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a category for scraped data that isn't grouped but I get this error. I'm wondering if there is a way I can get around it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MUHUMUZA IVAN\Desktop\JobPortal\test.py", line 128, in <module>
    the_category = Category.objects.get(title="Others")
  File "C:\Users\MUHUMUZA IVAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method 
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MUHUMUZA IVAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 397, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
jobapp.models.Category.DoesNotExist: Category matching query does not exist.
```

```
for test_job in final_jobs:

    if 'Manager' in test_job['title']:
        the_category = Category.objects.get(title='Manager')
    elif 'Engineer' in test_job['title']:
        the_category = Category.objects.get(title= 'Engineer')
    elif 'Architect' in test_job['title']:
        the_category = Category.objects.get(title='Architect')
    else:
        the_category = Category.objects.get(title="Others")
```

I know it says there is no query matching Others, how can I correct this.

Comment: Where do final_jobs come from?

Comment: From another website that I'm scraping data from

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create if doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766222/create-if-doesnt-exist)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I'm sort of trying to filter if a certain parameter exists in test_job then I create a category. then for whatever hasn't been grouped anywhere else, I want to create a category for them. That's where I'm failing at. I hope this makes my explanation a little clear.

Comment: What you describe is exactly the question linked above... you want to either get a `Category` object where the title is "Others" if it exists or create it and get it if it doesn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using **`Category.objects.get(title="...")`** in each **`if/elif`** block
you can choose one of these methods to get related `the_category` object:

### Custom function with handled `DoesNotExist` exception:

```py
def get_category_object(title):
    try:
        the_category = Category.objects.get(title='...')
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        the_category = None
```

### `get_object_or_404()` function:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

the_category = get_object_or_404(Category, title='...')
```

### `.get_or_create()` method:

```py
the_category, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(title='...')
```

### `.filter()` and `.first()` methods:

```py
the_category = Category.objects.filter(title='...').first()
```

Comment: i nested the if/elif blocks within the try and except and specified the error that was being thrown and i think its working well